# eclipse xtext plugin versions compatibility with eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, compatibility, xtext

I made a plugin in eclipse juno using xtext, I package my plugin using the following tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html#p2deployplugin ... sec 6.Create update site for your plug-in and I install it in the same version of eclipse IDE and the installation was successful. I need install it in others versions of eclipse's (Helios, Galileo, etc.) but when i try to install in Helios appear the following message:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: MView Source 1.0.0.201308011127 (MView.feature.group 1.0.0.201308011127)
  Missing requirement: MView Source 1.0.0.201308011127 (MView.feature.group 1.0.0.201308011127) requires 'org.eclipse.xtext 2.0.0' but it could not be found.
```

I searched for org.eclipse.xtext 2.0.0 jar to add to the dependencies but i dont found it. 
I don't know if this will work but I wanted to ask if there are some way to make my plugin compatible with various versions of eclipse IDE and how. compatible with backward versions and forward versions. I would appreciate any information about it. Sorry for my English Thank you very much. =)

Answer (score 0):

If an Eclipse installation does not contain Xtext, you need to provide Eclipse with the URL of the plugin repository (sometimes called update site) where it is located. That will enable Eclipse to discover and install your dependencies when installing your plugin. You can find the URLs that you need on Xtext website.

http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/download.html

Comment: You will need to clarify, what URL you've used, where you've added it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see the version of XTEXT plugin in both of eclipse instalations:

```
Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details.
```

In Plugins tab, search for **Xtext UI Core**

Sorry my english.

Answer (score -1):

A complete overview on:

1. All XText versions
2. The dependent XText core component versions
3. The corresponding Eclipse platform version
4. Links to the appropriate download / update sites

can be found here: [XText versions, dependencies and Eclipse platform matrix](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/350_continuous_integration.html#maven-tycho-hints)

An pretty useful example for a target platform configuration is there as well!

Comment: Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)